# Android web browser that allows zooming in on any page

Tags: android, web-browser, web, accessibility

Can anyone recommend an Android web browser that allows the user to zoom in on ***any*** web page?

I find that most Android web browsers can zoom in on *some* pages, but cannot zoom in on *every* page.

Prefer gratis, but all recommendations are welcome.  Open-source is a bonus, but not required.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable force zoom on Chrome. Go to Settings>Accessibility>Force enable zoom.

Hope it works for every website. I've tried it on a couple of sites which did not want to zoom and it worked so try it out!

If not, I think that [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser) also has an option for 'force zooming'.